# Cannot get "id" element

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a problem getting the id element to show in the `<p>`. Below is my sample coding, it cannot show my id element in the `<p>`. Hope someone can guide me on which part I a getting wrong. Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input id="try" type="text" value="testing"><br>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {

  var x = $('#try').attr('id');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  
 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Actually, I want the expected result like below the picture:

[image]

Comment: Where is "fname"? Do you want to show the "input" element "id" attribute value?

Comment: You are using jQuery, but haven't included the library/framework to your page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an jQuery selector and method but you haven't include jQuery.

```
var x = $('#try').attr('id');
```

If you want to use it then include jquery with

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you are looking for a plain JS solution then use getElementById as you did above and then read the id property .id

```
document.getElementById('try').id;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input id="try" type="text" value="testing"><br>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById('try').id;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  
 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go with plain javascript then you need to replace the below line code:

```
var x = $('#try').attr('id');
```

with this one:

```
var x = document.getElementById("try").getAttribute("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that you are using jquery library? Did you import the library itself?

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Because otherwise you are going to get a problem in console tag like this "$ is not defined"